# Apache Camel Rest DSL CORS Options

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm trying to implement a custom OPTIONS response based on the path of a rest call.

So for example I have:

```
rest("/employee/login").id("employee-login-options")
                .verb("options").route()
                .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", constant("https://example.com"))
                .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", constant(true))
                .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", constant("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"))
                .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", constant("Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization"))
                .setHeader("Allow", constant("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"));

rest("/login").id("login-options")
        .verb("options").route()
        .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", constant("*"))
        .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", constant("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"))
        .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", constant("Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"))
        .setHeader("Allow", constant("GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"));
```

So one route allows credentials and has a specific domain, the other responds with a wildcard.

The problem I am having is neither of them are being called. I can see the client making the OPTIONS request, but its not hitting my routes.

I have configured my rest config like so:

```
restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .scheme(JETTY_SCHEME)
                .port(JETTY_PORT);
```

I have also tried:

```
restConfiguration()
        .component("jetty")
        .scheme(JETTY_SCHEME)
        .port(JETTY_PORT)
        .enableCORS(true)
        .corsAllowCredentials(true)
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://hello.3en.codes")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
```

However this only works for one route, and I cant overwrite the headers on a per route basis

I'm using Camel version 2.20.0

Comment: Looks like the options method doesnt hit any routes due to this check: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/8d434546520f2434d4278575a732a5632acca664/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RestBindingAdvice.java#L142

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP Options requests will be bypassed from hitting any routes by this check:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/8d434546520f2434d4278575a732a5632acca664/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RestBindingAdvice.java#L142

But after a bit more investigating of the code, I have managed to figure out a solution to my problem:

If I keep my restConfiguration like so:

```
restConfiguration()
        .component("jetty")
        .scheme(JETTY_SCHEME)
        .port(JETTY_PORT)
        .enableCORS(true) // <-- Important
        .corsAllowCredentials(true) // <-- Important
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
```

And I Change my employee login route to this:

```
rest("/example").post("/employee/login").consumes("application/json")
  .route().to("direct:validateUserCredentials")
  .setHeader("Origin",constant("http://localhost:4100"));
```

By setting the "Origin" header at the end of the route, camel then uses this to populate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, meaning I can tailor the header on a per route basis. This only works when corsAllowCredentials is set to true in the restConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

If the origin is variable and you want to allow it and you have access to `HttpServletRequest`

```
rest("/example").post("/employee/login").consumes("application/json")
  .route().to("direct:validateUserCredentials")
  .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("Origin", extractOrigin(exchange))); 


private String extractOrigin(Exchange exchange) {
    HttpMessage httpMessage = (HttpMessage) exchange.getIn();
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request = httpMessage.getRequest();
    //CORS: using original http request
    //return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort();
    //CORS using original header
    return request.getHeader("Origin");
  }
```